# Parse notification not stable

Tags: parse-platform

I currently have a mobile-ios chat app working with Cloud Code, which can send messages.

But the push notifications seems to be very unstable.

Only a very small percentage of the notifications can actually get through to the devices even in the foreground.

I have tried following checking but still no luck:

1. Upload a new .p12 and updated provisioning files accordingly.
2. Toggle the "Client push enabled setting.

I don't dare to upload the app to AppStore before I can figure out where the problem is.

Please help out and advice!

Comment: Which parse server version you are using  ?

Comment: @RanHassid, PARSE DASHBOARD 1.0.19

Comment: you are using parse.com service or the open source parse-server?

Comment: For sandbox, I'm using open source parse-server, whose notification service  is very unstable. For live, I'm using SashiDo, which works well.